# Drools file not found exception

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io, drools

I have been able to succesfully read in rules from the directory `src/main/rules` and my drools project works just fine.

My issue arises however when I want to read a ruleset from a different directory for example I have a second drools project with identical rules. attempting to read in the rules from `/home/user/Documents/workspace/OtherProject/src/main/ruls/Ruleset.drl` results in the error

```
"/home/user/Documents/workspace/DroolsProject/src/main/rules/Ruleset.drl" cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I have checked multiple times that the file exists, even copying and pasting the output from `pwd` to my `PATH` variable (in the drools project) with no luck.

```
private static KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase(String ruleSet) throws Exception {
    KnowledgeBuilder builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    builder.add(
            ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(
                    "/home/user/Documents/workspace/DroolsProject/src/main/rules/Ruleset.drl"),
            ResourceType.DRL);
    KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = builder.getErrors();
    if (errors.size() > 0) {
        for (KnowledgeBuilderError error : errors)
            System.err.println(error);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse knowledge :(");
    }
    KnowledgeBase base = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    base.addKnowledgePackages(builder.getKnowledgePackages());
    return base;
}
```

This is the method that I am using to load the rules.

The end goal is to upload a rule file to a server (probably to `/tmp`) and run the the project using said rule file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow below approach to load rule file from filesystem:

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

File file = new File("path/to/Rule.drl");
org.kie.api.io.Resource resource = kieServices.getResources().newFileSystemResource(file).setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL);
kfs.write(resource);

KieBuilder Kiebuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs);
Kiebuilder.buildAll();
KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
KieSession ksession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the file not found issue. However now I am plagued with a new issue. `Cannot find KieModule: org.default:artifact:1.0.0` I read somewhere that it might be an issue with my rules? However it is a very simple rule with a single print statement... here is the rule https://ptpb.pw/geoL

Comment: I fxed it, for some reason it doesn't like '#' in the file :/ :facepalm: